# Problem RDP'ing to a windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

I have a windows server 2008 standard installation.

Up until this morning I could RDP into it without issue.  Now it's coming back with an error saying "the remote computer requires Network Level Authentication, which your computer does not support."

I'm RDPing FROM a Windows Server 2008 R2 install...

That error usually happens when you connect to it from an XP box, but this is from a 2008 R2 install that worked previously.

Comment: And you're sure that it's set to accept RDP connections from any client?

Comment: @pauska: Yes.  Config hasn't changed.

Comment: NOTE: this should be closed, see answer below.

Comment: No need to close it, come back in 48 hours and chose your answer as the accepted one :)

Comment: @ErikA:  Interesting and totally possible.  Add yours as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bet is that this was a time sync issue. NLA (which uses Kerberos) usually requires that the time between the server and client be within 300 seconds of each other. If the time skew is greater than this, authentication will fail.

Comment: I went back and reviewed the logs.  It looks like a time resync occurred after the reboot which is probably why it was resolved.

Comment: Cool. In that case, though, you ought to go through your systems and verify that the Windows Time Service is configured correctly. They shouldn't be getting that far out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

We rebooted the server and it "fixed" itself.

Around 3:30 am this morning the server stopped responding to web requests.  We attempted to remote in, but received the error about RDP version.

Odd to say the least, but bouncing it resolved the problem.